# How to do arithmetic operation in Mule poll frequency attribute?

Tags: mule, integer-arithmetic

I am storing poll frequency in a properties file in units of seconds. But the frequency attribute of "poll" component in Mule expects the frequency to be in milliseconds. How can I perform multiplication operation here? The below two does not seem to be working:

```
(1) <poll frequency="${GiantsNew.poll*1000}">
(2) <poll frequency="${GiantsNew.poll}*1000">
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A viable workaround would be to store the poll frequency in milliseconds instead?

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thought. But some how I do not have control over how the poll frequency is stored.

Comment: Do you mind showing how you load the properties file?

Comment: I would not be able to show the code here, but I can somehow manage to store the frequency in milliseconds in the properties file. The point is I want to do convert from seconds to milliseconds in the Mule flow file itself if possible.

Comment: Forgot to mention in the original post: I am using Mule 3.2, so can't use MEL

Comment: Asking differently: do you use Spring to load the properties file or Mule?

Comment: I use Spring to load the properties file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry Mule doesn't support [SpEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) in the `frequency` attribute so I had to build the horrible contraption shown below to implement your requirement using only configuration elements.

You could also create a custom class to parse the initial `properties` bean instead of using the `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` as I'm doing below.

```
<spring:beans>
    <util:properties id="properties" location="classpath:appProperties.properties" />
    <spring:bean id="giantsNewProperty"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
        p:targetObject-ref="properties" p:targetMethod="setProperty">
        <spring:property name="arguments">
            <spring:list>
                <spring:value>GiantsNewComputedPoll</spring:value>
                <spring:value>#{ T(java.lang.Integer).valueOf(properties.getProperty("GiantsNew.poll")) * 5 }</spring:value>
            </spring:list>
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>

    <spring:bean id="computedProperties" factory-bean="properties"
        factory-method="clone" depends-on="giantsNewProperty" />

    <context:property-placeholder
        properties-ref="computedProperties" />
</spring:beans>

...

<poll frequency="${GiantsNewComputedPoll}">
```

Comment: is there many other attributes that don't support SpEL? I'm not sure I get why Mule doesn't support it there

Comment: It's a bug, and I don't know how many others like this there are.

Comment: must be, can't even do this:  <jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint queryTimeout="-1"
   pollingFrequency="#[60*60*1000]"

Comment: This is not SpEL but MEL. MEL is rarely if ever evaluated in inbound endpoints. Try with SpEL.

Comment: hmm, no luck "#[spel:2*1000]"  NumberFormatException:

Comment: Never seen this syntax. SpEL is typically within `#{ }`.

Comment: #{} is not allowed in my case :(

Comment: Bug then. JIRA it and share the JIRA number here please.